Group theoretical approach to conservation laws in classical mechanics
I'm doing some major procrastination instead of studying for my exam, but I wanted to share my thought just to confirm if I'm right.
Suppose that the action, $S(\mathcal{L})$ forms the basis of a representation of some one parameter group $G(s)$ that acts on the coordinates $q_i,\dot{q_i}$ and transforms them into $Q_i,\dot{Q_i}$. Then the generator of that group would be
$$ XS(\mathcal{L})=-i\frac{\partial}{\partial s}T_{G}(s)S(\mathcal{L}(q_i\dot{q_i},t))|_{s=0}=-i\frac{\partial}{\partial s}S(\mathcal{L}(Q_i,\dot{Q_i},t))|_{s=0}$$
$$ =-i \Bigg[\Big[\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial s}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial Q_i}+\frac{\partial \dot{Q_i}}{\partial s}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{Q_i}}\Big]\frac{\delta S}{\delta \mathcal{L}}\Bigg]_{s=0}=-i\Big[\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial s}\Bigg|_{s=0} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q_i}+\frac{\partial \dot{Q_i}}{\partial s}\Bigg|_{s=0} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q_i}}\Big]\frac{\delta}{\delta \mathcal{L}}S$$
Then X can be written in the form $X(s)=-i g(\mathcal{L})\frac{\delta}{\delta \mathcal{L}}$ where g is some function of the Lagrangian. Now, we see that the group can then represented as
$$ T_{G}(s)S(\mathcal{L})=e^{s g(\mathcal{L})\frac{\delta}{\delta \mathcal{L}}}S(\mathcal{L})=S(\mathcal{L}-sg(\mathcal{L})) $$
Now let's say that we want this group to preserve the Lagrangian for which the action is stationary, that is we want the action to represent the same physical system. Then we want $g(\mathcal{L})$ to be $0$ around $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q_i}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q_i}}=0$ and we want $\frac{\partial g(\mathcal{L})}{\partial \mathcal{L}}\neq 0$. The first condition yields (using $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q_i}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q_i}}$ where $S$ is stationary)
$$ g(\mathcal{L}_{stat})=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial s}\Bigg|_{s=0}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L_{stat}}}{\partial \dot{q_i}})=0$$
on its own this condition is not very interesting. Now, if instead the action of the group is
$$ T_{G}(s)S(\mathcal{L}(q_i\dot{q_i},t))=S(\mathcal{L}(Q_i,\dot{Q_i},t)+\frac{dF}{dt})$$
then the group preserves the Lagrangian for which the action is stationary if
$$ g(\mathcal{L}_{stat})=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial s}\Bigg|_{s=0}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L_{stat}}}{\partial \dot{q_i}}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial s}\Bigg|_{s=0})=0$$
which implies that
$$ C = \frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial s}\Bigg|_{s=0}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L_{stat}}}{\partial \dot{q_i}}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial s}\Bigg|_{s=0}$$
is a conserved quantity. If $F$ has terms quadratic (or greater powers) in $s$, then they will play no role in the expression above, so in the treatment of conserved quantities, it's easier to assume whitout loss of generality $F(s,q_i,\dot{q_i},t)=s f(q_i,\dot{q_i},t)$. So the conclusion is that if the Lagrangian changes like $\mathcal{L}(q_i,\dot{q_i},t)=\mathcal{L}(Q_i,\dot{Q_i},t)+s\frac{df}{dt}(q_i,\dot{q_i},t)$ under a change of coordinates, then
$$ C = \frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial s}\Bigg|_{s=0}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L_{stat}}}{\partial \dot{q_i}}+f(q_i,\dot{q_i},t) $$
is a conserved quantity, which is something like Noether's theorem. Is this approach legitimate or interesting at all or should I have studied for my exams instead?
